GCP Serverless VPC Access Connector - Failed to Get Healthy
I have an App Engine running on europe-west1 (app engine location is europe-west). I need to connect to my DB that is also running on europe-west1. To achieve this, apparently, I need to have a Serverless VPC Access Connector. That's fine so far.
However, when I try to create a connector, it always fails by complaining about quotas (as could be seen in the message below).
Unknown error. Original error message: An internal error occurred:
VPC Access connector failed to get healthy. Please check GCE quotas, logs and org policies and recreate.

However, when I check the quotas, I do not see anything that is possibly causing this issue.

I've tried anything to open space in the quota (even downgrading my DB to an F1 shared CPU instance :) )
I tried other regions to create the connector and it succeeds but in those cases I cannot connect my app engine as it's not in the same region as the connector. Thus, it has be created in europe-west1.
I'm open to any suggestions or ideas!

@ balgam Did you have time to check my answer? It helped you to solve your issue? If not, I am happy to assist further.

Unfortunately, it didn't help either @SaiChandiniRouthu . Sorry, I was trying to arrange with my teammates as well. That's why, it took a little longer

@ balgam I have updated my Answer. Please check  EDIT-1 Section.

Did you have time to check my answer? It helped you to solve your problem? If yes,could you please have a look at this doc and accordingly proceed

As per this official  document:
The error you are facing due to the If an organizational policy constraint constraints/compute.trustedImageProjects does not have an allow on the Serverless Image Project  projects/serverless-vpc-access-images  the creation of Virtual Private Cloud Serverless access connector fails.
To resolve your issue follow below steps :


Create the connector using a name no longer than 25 characters. Check if the name exceeds 25 characters or includes a hyphen. Although
the console user interface does not allow more than 25 characters, you
may exceed this limit via gcloud CLI or the REST API's.
Ensure the Serverless VPC Access image from the console's internal project projects/serverless-vpc-access-images is trusted for use in
your project where the VPC connector lies:
This could be done by adding the Serverless Image Project: projects/serverless-vpc-access-images to the list of allowed values in
theRestriction:constraints/compute.trustedImageProjects. Refer to
Set image access constraints for more information.


Refer to this GCP  official document and similar resolved issue on google cloud community forum  about more information about the error you are facing.
EDIT-1
Most of the customers are not able to create connectors in europe-west1. There seems to be an ongoing public issue with that specific region as it is out of capacity.
I will recommend you to add a star and monitor the following similar Public Issue where other users asked about europe-west1 region also from GCP's Issue Tracker to get the most updated information from the relevant team.
When you try to create the connector using the GCP Console instead of the relevant gcloud commands the europe-west1 region doesn't even show up.

As an alternative, seeing this is a capacity issue in some Google regions for these Serverless VPC Access Connectors: if you can run your application in Cloud Run instead (most containers will run just fine in Cloud Run, and cheaper at that as well) you can use "Direct VPC egress with a VPC network". This does not require additional VMs and has "Lower latency, higher throughput" as a bonus.
